# How do I cleanly map / sort / fold / sort / expand using only cascades or chained calls, in Dart?

Tags: dart

I would like to perform the following operations on a source list:

- map
- toList
- sort
- fold
- sort
- expand
- toList

Some of these methods, like map and toList are chainable, because they return a non-null object. However, the `sort` method returns `void` as it operates on a List and does not return a list.

Dart has a [method cascade operator](http://news.dartlang.org/2012/02/method-cascades-in-dart-posted-by-gilad.html), which works great for method calls that do not return `this` or another object.

I'm having a hard time writing the above sequence of calls without resorting to assigning a variable after the `sort` and then starting the chain of calls again.

I'd like to write the equivalent of:

```
return thing
         .map(...)
         .toList()
         .sort(...)
         .fold(...)
         .sort(...)
         .expand(...)
         .toList();
```

The closest I can get is:

```
var thing
      .map(...)
      .toList()
        ..sort(...);

var otherThing = thing
                   .fold(...)
                     ..sort(...);

var finalThing = otherThing.expand(...).toList();
```

Is there a better way? How do I "break out" of the cascade and continue on a chain?

Comment: There's an issue opened on this topic : [Move sort to Iterable, return an iterable (instead of changing the collection in place)](http://dartbug.com/8762).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Can you add some parens? I guess something like this...

```
return ((thing
         .map(...)
         .toList()..sort(...))
           .fold(...)..sort(...))
             .expand(...)
             .toList();
```

Comment: @Nican - Rolled back your edit, as Seth is aware of method cascades. He uses them in his question.

Comment: The person who asked the question does; Another reader reading the question (like me up to 5 minutes ago) does not.

Comment: Ok - I updated Seth's question to add a link to this article. http://news.dartlang.org/2012/02/method-cascades-in-dart-posted-by-gilad.html

Comment: I updated the post with the link. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Thanks @GregLowe. I wish we had a sort that returned the list, it would make this much easier.

Comment: could you not just extend off of `list` and override `sort` to return the list afterwards?